# How to write this as the sum of two orthogonal vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

The system says that my answer is wrong. [image]

First I found the projection of $\overrightarrow y$ onto $\overrightarrow u$, which is $\overrightarrow x_1$ and the $\overrightarrow x_2$ is subtracting $\overrightarrow y$(original) from $\overrightarrow x_1$.

Comment: Your numbers are wrong. For $x_1$ I got $\left(-\frac{182}{33}, -\frac{104}{33}, \frac{26}{33}\right).

Comment: i'm not getting x2 right. i'm getting (-47/33,137/33,205/33)/ Shouldn't it just be y-x1 to get x2?

Comment: It's $-49/33$ in the first component.